# Ubuntu mate sd card for Raspberry pi

Tags: mate, sd-card

Im trying to create a micro SD card with Ubuntu mate and trying to follow these steps.

http://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/

My lsblk command throws this following output -

lsblk

```
NAME           MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda              8:0    0   477G  0 disk  
├─sda2           8:2    0     1K  0 part  
├─sda7           8:7    0  15.4G  0 part  
│ └─cryptswap1 253:0    0  15.4G  0 crypt [SWAP]
├─sda5           8:5    0  15.4G  0 part  
├─sda1           8:1    0 234.5G  0 part  
└─sda6           8:6    0 211.6G  0 part  /
mmcblk0        179:0    0  29.7G  0 disk  
└─mmcblk0p1    179:1    0  29.7G  0 part  /media/prem/3163-6330
```

what should my ddrescue command be -  should it be /dev/mmcblk0?

```
sudo ddrescue -D --force ubuntu-mate-16.04.2-desktop-armhf-raspberry-pi.img /dev/sdx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the Tutorial from your [Link](http://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/) (It is also shown in the video)

```
The microSDHC may be presented on any /dev/sdX so use the command lsblk to check.
```

Just use the Device name and not the partition. So just

```
/dev/mmcblk0
```